# Split specific element attribute into multiple rows based on delimiter

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am trying to transform an XML and split the third App_Data element Value into multiple duplicate rows based on the commas from:

```
    <Metadata>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Run_Time" Value="01:30:57"/>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Year" Value="2016"/>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Category" Value="2330, 2470, 1373"/>
    </Metadata>
```

to look exactly like this:

```
    <Metadata>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Run_Time" Value="01:30:57"/>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Year" Value="2016"/>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Category" Value="2330"/>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Category" Value="2470"/>
        <App_Data App="VOD" Name="Category" Value="1373"/>
    </Metadata>
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- P.S. Do a search for *tokenize*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for the quick reply! I'm using the 1.0 example in this example, however it only makes the attributes into child -elements when I need attributes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544336/how-do-i-explode-an-attribute-with-values-separated-by-a-into-seperate-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only makes the attributes into child -elements when I need
>   attributes

Actually, your example shows that you do need an element for each token.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="App_Data[@Name='Category']">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@Value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="', '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <App_Data App="{@App}" Name="Category" Value="{$token}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer a shorter (but non-reusable) version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="App_Data[@Name='Category']" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="@Value"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="', '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <App_Data App="{@App}" Name="Category" Value="{$token}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked like a charm. I know it doesn't matter but one small thing: How can i preserve the elements to end on one line i.e. <App_Data /> vs <App_Data></App_Data>.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Is your result different from the one here: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYjq ?

Comment: @michal.hor257k Sorry michael nevermind it is a problem with my vba script thank you so much!!!