# Need an XSLT for-each that will take multiple filenames in a source tag, and split it into separate tags on the output

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need a xsl for-each that will convert my source XML to MARCXML while taking multiple filenames from a single source tag, and populating a separate tag for each filename in the output.

Source XML:

```
<tag856ID>NEWS20010525003-01.TIF; NEWS20010525004-02.TIF; NEWS20010525005-03.TIF; NEWS20010525006-04.TIF</tag856ID>
```

Expected Output:

```
<marc:datafield ind2=" " ind1="4" tag="856">
  <marc:subfield code="u">NEWS20010525003-01.TIF</marc:subfield>
</marc:datafield>
<marc:datafield ind2=" " ind1="4" tag="856">
  <marc:subfield code="u">NEWS20010525004-02.TIF</marc:subfield>
</marc:datafield>
<marc:datafield ind2=" " ind1="4" tag="856">
  <marc:subfield code="u">NEWS20010525005-03.TIF</marc:subfield>
</marc:datafield>
<marc:datafield ind2=" " ind1="4" tag="856">
  <marc:subfield code="u">NEWS20010525004-04.TIF</marc:subfield>
</marc:datafield>
```

My current XSL:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="tag856ID">
   <marc:datafield tag="856"  ind1="4" ind2=" ">
     <marc:subfield code="u">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </marc:subfield>
   </marc:datafield>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Which puts all 4 filenames into the same tag.  I need to have separate tags for each.  This is xsl 1.0

Comment: You cannot do this with xsl:for-each. Do a search for `tokenize` - for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274519/split-specific-element-attribute-into-multiple-rows-based-on-delimiter/38274808#38274808

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!!!