# split different element attribute into multiple duplicate rows

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform XML, I have multiple and different input. I tried many solutions like
[Split specific element attribute into multiple rows based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274519/split-specific-element-attribute-into-multiple-rows-based-on-delimiter)
but in my case I have different element with different attribute.
Any suggestions please?

Input:

```
<ROOT>
<Data X="1233" Y="1:30:57" Z="abcd"/>
<Info T="1:30:57" F="xyz" H="1234" "/>
```

Excepted Output:

```
<ROOT>
    <Data X="1233"/>
    <Data Y="1:30:57"/>
    <Data Z="abcd"/>
    <Info T="1:30:57 />
    <Info F="xyz" />
    <Info H="1234"/>
```

Comment: Neither your input XML **nor** your output XML are _well-formed_. Do you think that this is a good question?

Comment: Your XML is still not _well-formed_ There is a superfluous `"` at the end of your `Info` element and the `ROOT` element is not closed.

Comment: However, I added a final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you format your input properly

```
<document>
    <ROOT>
        <Data X="1233" Y="1:30:57" Z="abcd"/>
        <Info T="1:30:57" F="xyz" H="1234"/>
    </ROOT>
</document>
```

This should do it

```
<xsl:template match="Data | Info">
    <xsl:for-each select="./@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(./parent::node())}">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />                
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

A solution to your problem is the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data | Info">
    <xsl:variable name="nod" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{$nod}">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <Data X="1233"/>
    <Data Y="1:30:57"/>
    <Data Z="abcd"/>
    <Info T="1:30:57"/>
    <Info F="xyz"/>
    <Info H="1234"/>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not actually well formed, meaning your attributes are not formatted properly.

```
<ROOT>
    <Data "X=1233,Y=1:30:57,Z=abcd"/>
    <Info " T=1:30:57,F=xyz,H=1234 "/>
</ROOT>
```

Should really be

```
<ROOT>
    <Data X="1233" Y="1:30:57" Z="abcd"/>
    <Info T="1:30:57" F="xyz" H="1234"/>
</ROOT>
```

If you must work with what you've got, you might be able to do something with xsl:analyze-string, but I'm dubious about that because the data is not well-formed XML.I don't think you'll be able to parse the attributes as they are.

Comment: Thank you for reply... if my input is well formed ... how i can split attribute into multiple rows?